# Toggle JDialog visibility on button press or lose focus

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jdialog, focuslistener

Java Gurus,

Looking to toggle a JDialog's visibility when a JButton is pressed or when the JDialog loses focus i.e. when another area of the screen outside the JDialog becomes active. Lose focus is working fine, as it's handed by the WindowFocusListener but I can't get the functionality for the JButton i.e. 1st click => JDialog visible, 2nd click => JDialog invisible, 3rd click => JDialog visible.

I don't really want to go down the route of making the JDialog modal or by counting the clicks on the button.

Any ideas of achieving the above functionality in a simple, clean way?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowFocusListener;

import javax.swing.*;


public class TestFrameExample {

    public static void main(String s[]) {

        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        final JButton button = new JButton();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Help me toggle JDialog!");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Dialog visibility should toggle when JButton is pressed!");

        button.setText("Toggle Dialog");
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                //Execute when button is pressed
                dialog.setVisible(!dialog.isVisible());
                dialog.setLocation(new Point(button.getLocationOnScreen().x, button.getLocationOnScreen().y+30));
            }
        }); 
        dialog.setSize(new Dimension(110,80));
        dialog.setVisible(false);
        dialog.setBackground(null);
        dialog.setModal(false);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        dialog.setUndecorated(true);
        dialog.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowFocusListener(){
            public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent arg0) {
                dialog.setVisible(false);
            }
            public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {

            }
        });
        ((JComponent) dialog.getContentPane()).setBorder(new RoundedBorder(Color.gray, 1,1,12));
        ((JComponent) dialog.getContentPane()).setOpaque(false);

        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(button);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(350, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dialog.setVisible(!dialog.isVisible());
```

Comment: Yes that's what I tried, I've edited my code sample to reflect this. The WindowFocusListener always sets the JDialog's visibility to false and therefore the ActionListener will always set the JDialog's visibility to true

Comment: i suggest that focus lost event occours when window hides by click on the button, insert debug output to your code please

Comment: Correct, it does.. I am aware of this

Comment: If my answer was helpful for you, please mark it as correct by clicking on a checkbox on the left of page =) thank you!